# Publishing websites on azure

Tags: azure, model-view-controller

I published my website on azure, but I just get the plain HTML page. I uploaded my MVC 5 project. How do i get the images and script published?Is there any way that the published website can be linked ?

Comment: Found the answer! had issue with the style bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally it is dependent upon the style bundles and i see that you already got it right.

Answer (score 1):

The error is generally with Style Bundles. You must have forgotten to link the scripts or stylesheets. Look for bundles.config and find if the correct file has been linked.

Comment: Thanks, did it earlier. Although, great to get a reply.